# Невозможно подключиться к серверу MS SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день/вечер/утро/ночь! Прошу помощи. Не могу подключиться к локальному серверу. Что сделала: удалила и заново поставила ядро и менеджмент студио, перезапустила вручную все службы. Почему-то не запускается служба SQL Server Agent. Насколько смогла разобраться вроде она не влияет на соединение с сервером. Стоит SQl Server 2022/ SQL Server Managment Studio 19.3/ Windows 11

[image: службы][image: ошибка соединение с сервером]

Comment: SQL Server Agent здесь действительно нипричём. А по сути вопроса в Интернете полно ответов, погуглите. Не вижу смысла их здесь повторять.

Comment: SQL Server Agent выполняет специфические задачи вроде резервного копирования по расписанию, зеркалирования БД и пр. Поскольку таких задач (ещё) нет, то и служба не запускается.

Comment: Я гуглила. Я спрашивала у других знакомых программистов. Ну не помогают эти решения.

Answer (score 1):

В MMC найдите свой экземпляр СУБД ИмяЭкземпляра (на картинке это TDAS), который вы создавали при установке. Обращаться к нему в SSMS нужно как "ИмяКомпьютера\ИмяЭкземпляра" (или ".\ИмяЭкземпляра", если локально).

Включите все клиентские протоколы. Сделайте перезапуск сервиса (из контекстного меню для "SQL Server (ИмяЭкземпляра)".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай проверьте, что экземпляр не скрыт (Hide Instance = No), выбрав Properties в контекстном меню для "Protocols for ИмяЭкземпляра" (возможно, может потребоваться перезапуск сервиса в случае изменения).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ) Это я настраивала. Я смогла это решить. И знаете как? В имени сервера написала .\SQLEXPRESS. Вот так вот просто. Ни название компьютера, ни имя_комп\SQLEXPRESS, ни 127.0.0.1. Это первое, что я проверяла. Почему оно в моменте перестало работать, большой вопрос. Но тут, как говориться, магия вне Хогвартса.

Comment: и имя_компьютера/SQLEXPRESS тоже работает

Comment: А зачем я вам, Лилечка, про удар Лемана тут два часа рассказывал??? (из к.ф. "Классик"). Нужно вам теперь за мои усилия отметить мой ответ как принятый.